# Spring Boot : How to make small jar package and share dependencies from external folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, package

I have to deploy multiple spring boot applications on the same Linux server in the client location. Each application contains the same dependencies and each application file size is 50mb so how we can create a common library folder so that all spring boot application shares the same dependencies from one location. this may create my application jar or war file small. Please help me with this.

Any suggestion or blogs links will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi for this question that you have asked

> so how we can create a common library folder so that all spring boot application shares the same dependencies from one location

In pom.xml add **maven-dependency-plugin** with goal as **copy-dependencies** and under this you can set the output directory for the common library folder

Example

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now you can use the below, to create two jar, one jar with all dependencies(named as appname-exec.jar) included, another jar with only class files (appname.jar)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now you can use the **jar only with class files (appname.jar)**, because the **size will be much lower since it has no dependencies included**.

There is one last step needs to be configured in order to work with the jar (appname.jar), is to add the class path entry that is the common location jar and to add your main class name inside  tag.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
       </manifest>
    </archive>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now you can put these three together in you pom.xml under build section as per you project strucure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spring-boot-thin-launcher` to build executable and thin Spring Boot jar. It is available for both `maven` and `gradle`.

**Maven:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.28.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**Gradle:**

```
plugins {
    //other plugins goes here ...
    id 'org.springframework.boot.experimental.thin-launcher' version '1.0.28.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

You can run Spring Boot thin JAR by command

```
java -jar my-app-1.0.jar --thin.root=path/to/dependency/jars
```

You can have look at:

- Official Plugin Page:
  https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher
- Tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-thin-jar